# How to store result of CASE expression into (temporary/not) variable and use it to calculate concurrently inside the same SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, case

In other programing language we can do this:

```
A = 5
B = A + 7
```

But anyone know how to do this in SQL, something like this:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN t.[Id] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1 THEN a.[123]
        ELSE a.[432] END) AS 'Points',
     @'Points' + 5 AS 'FinalPoints'   ---Does any way to do this
FROM  DeliveryOrder AS do
LEFT JOIN Transaction AS t ON t.DOId = do.Id 
LEFT JOIN Amount AS a ON do.Id = a.Id
```

I really appreciate if anyone have any ideas how to do this

P/S: Since I can use SubQuery to simulate this but in my case, each columns have many CASE..WHEN expression and inside it have Case expression too so after all when combine all of them into single SubQuery make thing so terrible to read :(

Comment: You could use a SubQuery or a CTE

Comment: @Sami yes i can use subquery inside it but since I have more than 4 CASE expression for each column and combine them into one subquery make thing very awful :(

Comment: *"In other programing language we can do this:"* SQL Isn't a programming language, so what applies to *other programming languages* doesn't apply. SQL is a **query** language; they don't follow the same rules. Don't treat SQL like a Programming language because it **isn't** one. Also it's a `CASE` expression; `Case` (`Switch`) statements are not available in T-SQL.

Comment: Please do not post invalid code as description, it doesn't mean anything. Iit doesn't communicate to us what you want, you are assuming an interpretation of the code that you don't give, like some order of evaluation. Use words to explain. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what you want. Aliases defined in the `select` clause cannot be reused in the same clause, so you need to either repeat the expression, or use a derived table (subquery or cte).

Your nested `case` seems overkill - I think that your code can be simplified as:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t.[Id] IS NULL THEN 10 ELSE 5 END AS points,
    CASE WHEN t.[Id] IS NULL THEN 15 ELSE 10 END finalPoints
FROM  DeliveryOrder AS do
LEFT JOIN Transaction AS t ON t.DOId = do.Id
```

Or using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    points,
    points + 5 finalPoints
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN t.[Id] IS NULL THEN 10 ELSE 5 END AS points
    FROM  DeliveryOrder AS do
    LEFT JOIN Transaction AS t ON t.DOId = do.Id 
) t
```

Comment: The nested `case` I made is the example, I have updated the new one which is apporoximate same as my case

Answer (score 0):

Using a SubQuery

```
SELECT Points, Points + 5 AS FinalPoints
FROM
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN T.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1 THEN 5 ELSE 10 END Points
  FROM DeliveryOrder AS DO
  LEFT JOIN [Transaction] AS T ON DO.Id = T.DOId
) T
```

You could get ride of the nested `CASE` expression and directly use

```
CASE WHEN T.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 5 ELSE 10 END Points
```

Answer (score 0):

One another way can be to use cross apply,

```
SELECT
  p.Points
  ,p.Points+5 'FinalPoints' 
FROM  DeliveryOrder AS do
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Transaction] AS t ON t.DOId = do.Id 
cross apply (
select CASE WHEN T.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 5 ELSE 10 END  AS 'Points'
) p
```